# Fill dates array and add dummy variables

Tags: excel

I have a column with dates called "dates". This column contain dates from 01.01.2010 to 31.12.2010. it should have about 365 rows, but it actually has only 231 rows, because the data was not collected regularly. The others are missing, and I'd like to fill the gaps in time.

How can I fill the array of this column with the missing dates? I want to add 134 rows in the place of the missing ones, filling in the missing dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create another sheet and put all the dates in column A in your new sheet.
- Make sure your sheet with the data in it has the data column all the way on the left (important for how Vlookup works)
- In your new sheet, starting in Cell `B2` put numbers 1 through however many columns you have in your data sheet along that top row.
- In your new sheet use Vlookup to find all the rows where there are data

  `=VLOOKUP($A2,DataSheet!$A$1:$C$20,B1,FALSE)`
- Note that the lookup column (`$A1`) is locked in to the column but not the row and that the range you are looking up is locked in in all directions. This will allow you to drag to the right/down and fill everything in.
- Drag to the right then drag all the way down.

there will be `#N/A`s where you cannot find a match which you can suppress with either an IF statement of conditional formatting. But now you have a row for every day with blanks when there is not data!

Comment: Probably I miss something very important, because it gives me some error. If I "Make sure your sheet with the data in it has the data column all the way on the left", have one more column called "values" on the next to the column "dates", do I have to paste them together in the new sheet? Then column A will be filled with the column of "values" and cell B2 will be filled with the first date of the column "dates", so I suppose that have to put this single number 2 (because i have 2 columns at all) in cell C2. Then where is this single number in the formula? Could you explain with more steps ?

Comment: I find a solution with a similar farmula but the result was the same. First i gat the two columns of data - "date" and "values" in the columns A and B of the worksheet each consisted of 231 rows. Then i spread a full array of dates - 365 in a new column D, than i put this formula: =VLOOKUP(D2;$A$2:$B$1056;2;FALSE) in C2 and obtained the only the values from column "values" corresponded to the new dates of column D :) .... Brad thank you for directing me to the Vlookup function :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with a similar formula, but the result was the same.

First, I got the two columns of data—"date" and "values" in the columns A and B of the worksheet. Each consisted of 231 rows. Then, I spread a full array of dates—365 in a new column D. Finally, I used this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2;$A$2:$B$1056;2;FALSE)
```

in C2 and obtained the only the values from column "values" corresponded to the new dates of column D.

Thanks for [Brad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23664788) for directing me to the `VLOOKUP` function.